# Excel stop printing empty cells which contain formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an Excel sheet containing Data and every cell in a specific range contains the formula "=sheet!cellnumber" where it takes the input from another sheet.

The problem is, when I want to print via vba macro or normal print, Excel prints the blank cells, which only contain the formula, too. So I think of a macro, where it loops until a Blank cell is found and then prints every page until the first blank cell where just the formula is.

I hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are your preferences set to print formulae?

Comment: Where do I find this setting?